# does npm works serving dependencies directly from registry always or cache?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am setting up a local npm registry, I think a docker container would be best option to go for, rather , while digging I came across 2 different containers [ymedlop/npm-cache-resource](https://hub.docker.com/r/ymedlop/npm-cache-resource) and [orlandohohmeier/local-npm](https://hub.docker.com/r/orlandohohmeier/local-npm/),

when running npm install ,

is it looking for straight away to pull from registry set or from the cache.

is it possible to check `~/.npm` cache first always or just use cache only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use only cached packages set offline mode in npm:

```
$ npm config set offline true
```

Then:

```
$ npm install
```

Or to prefer cached packages set:

```
$ npm config set prefer-offline true
```

More information you can find in npm config [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config).

Comment: this approach sounds very medivial

Comment: Use prefer-offline option to check cache first.